# In a CLI Cocoa application, how does one implement a event loop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-location

I have a Delegate class that handles responses from CLLocationManager and prints them via printf(). Is there some type of busy loop I can put in main() so that the program stays open and keeps CLLocationManager connected to Delegate happily processing events?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Delegate.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Delegate *del = [Delegate alloc];

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = del;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // Something goes here

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `CLLocationManager` runs its cool stuff on another thread an you just need something to keep your program alive, you may use `NSApplicationMain(argc, argv)` or `dispatch_main()` (from `<dispatch/dispatch.h>`), at your convenience. Though `dispatch_main` will never return, so there's no chance `[pool drain]` will ever be called.

Comment: Wound up using NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]; [runLoop run];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what NSRunLoop is for, and [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/) is explicitly documented as requiring one (search for “run loop” on that page), so that's what you need to do: Run the run loop.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried `NSRunLoop` but it didnt work for me, i'm brand new to writing C++ apps, may you please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704702/creating-a-main-event-loop-for-hotkeys-etc