# Creating a main event loop (for hotkeys etc)

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c++, macos-carbon

I am trying to write a stand alone app to register a global hotkey. Below is my code which I compile with `gcc -framework Foundation -framework AppKit -framework Carbon -lstdc++ namsg.mm -o namsg`.

I have put in a

```
    do {
        event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture] inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode dequeue:YES];
        if (event != nil) {
            [self handleEvent:event];
        }
    } while(true);
```

however my hotkey of (Command + 3) is not picked up. This hotkey combination does work because as I was able to pull off this code using javascript FFI, but now I am trying to do it with Objective-C++.

I also tried

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

Is there another way I should create the main event loop?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

void showAlert() {
    NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hi there."];
    [alert runModal];
}

OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler, EventRef theEvent, void *userData) {
    //Do something once the key is pressed
    showAlert();

    return noErr;
}

void registerHotkey() {
    EventHotKeyRef gMyHotKeyRef;
    EventHotKeyID gMyHotKeyID;
    EventTypeSpec eventType;
    eventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
    eventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyPressed;

    OSStatus installed = InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,NULL,NULL);

    gMyHotKeyID.signature='htk1';
    gMyHotKeyID.id=1;

    OSStatus registered = RegisterEventHotKey(20, cmdKey, gMyHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &gMyHotKeyRef);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    registerHotkey();


    NSEvent* event;

    do {
        event = [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask untilDate:[NSDate distantFuture] inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode dequeue:YES];
        if (event != nil) {
            [self handleEvent:event];
        }
    } while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First thing is that NSApp isn't created automatically; you likely want to call `NSApplicationMain()`. Although there might be another way, that's the standard way to create an `NSApplication` and a run loop. Second, what is `[self handleEvent:event]` meant to do? You're not in an ObjC method there; is there a global `self` somewhere?

Comment: Are you working with GNUStep, or Apple's Cocoa?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm a beginner at this. I'm a javscript guy. It didn't cause any errors, just warning in compile time so I tried it. Thanks so much for your reply. I will search up `NSApplicationMain` right away!

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm pretty sure it's Cocoa, here is a screeshot of me working on it - http://i.imgur.com/OI7vumm.png

Comment: If you were working with GNUStep, I imagine you'd know it. :) Do you have a copy of Xcode? It would probably simplify your life a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much @JoshCaswell for trying to help me. I wanted badly to move away from javascript FFI to actually writing C/C++ - Xcode won't work for me :( I tried real hard. :(